# ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, scroll

Even I've searched on google I want to be very sure about a thing.
Does `ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY` means that I will receive the results in the order they are in DB?

I have something like:

```
Scroller<Integer> foundRecs = new Scroller<Integer>(query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY));
```

Maybe is a stupid question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That specific API is Hibernate, which I don't know too much about, but I guess it maps down to [`TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) in the end (and [its documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/ScrollMode.html#FORWARD_ONLY) agrees by mentioning that constant).

If that's the case, then **no**: this **will not** influence the order in which items are returned.

It **only** means that you can only traverse the result once and can only navigate forward (not backwards).

Databases don't really **have** an "order" in which they store data, because their tables are sets (not lists). If you need some order for your results, then you need to add an `ORDER BY` to your SQL (or the equivalent in whichever query system you use).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rely on the physical order of data in the database. This **might** work if you query only a single table, but will fail as soon as you are using joins.
If you want your data to appear in a specific order, you need an ORDER BY clause.